# Jquery manipulate urls

Tags: javascript, jquery, pyrocms

I am using pyrocms and all nav links are absolute links which won't allow me to make smooth scrolling work on the page.

My smooth scrolling script is

.js

```
$('.nav a').click(function() {
     $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop : $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
```

and with pyrocms my links looks like this to divs on the same page

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com/index.php/#somelink>Link on the same page</a>
```

Problem with this is my animate won't work with absoulte urls for some reason. Am I missing something simple, or do I need to convert my links to relative (href="#somelink") with jquery. Is that a possibility. I only need this to work on my nav links as they are all links on the index.php page.

Comment: try: `scrollTop : $(this.hash).offset().top`  http://jsfiddle.net/FkX2L/

Comment: Exactly what was needed. I was sure there was a better way then what I was trying. If you add this as an answer I will mark it so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use property `hash` of the anchor tag:

```
scrollTop : $(this.hash).offset().top
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FkX2L/)